# Synergistic effects: what statistics should I use?

Tags: anova, interaction, multiple-comparisons, model, group-differences

I have one control group and three treatment groups. These three groups are treated with substance $A$, $B$, and $A + B$.

After treatment, the measurements compared to the control changed by $x,$ $y$, $z$, respectively.

It is straightforward to test differences among three groups using ANOVA. But how do I test for any synergistic effects of the combined substance (i.e., $A + B$) treatment?

For example, $z > x + y$ or $z < x + y$ would indicate a synergistic effect.

$z = x + y$ would suggest that combining $A + B$ only has an additive effect.

What statistics can I use to test this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Tukey's HSD (honestly significant difference) test would let you make pairwise comparisons across each of the treatments. You could compare A to A + B and B to A + B. This would give you some idea of the 'synergistic' effect.

Comment: Thanks, ralph! Thats exactly what I am looking for. How to set up such contrast in R or other statistical software?

Answer (score 2):

Statistics cannot tell you if an interaction is synergistic!

You need to characterise the dose-response relationship of both agents and see if both together yields an effect that is greater than expected from an appropriate increment of dose for both agents. It's is not easy where the synergism is modest. You will find a large (and inconsistent, I'm sorry to say) literature on determining synergy in the pharmacological literature.

I'll say it again: statistics cannot tell you if an interaction is synergistic!  What you need is a carefully devised experimental design.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the 'synergistic' effect, you can use Tukey's HSD test.

Tukey's HSD is post hoc test, and is used in conjunction with an ANOVA. It lets you pinpoint significant differences between treatments. In your example, you can compare A to A + B and B to A + B. Based on the outcome of Tukey's HSD, you can then argue that the combination of A and B has different effect than just A or B alone.

See the TukeyHSD function in R (this comes default with the base distribution of R).

Comment: Thanks, ralph !  I understand that compare A to A + B and B to A + B, which would help assess whether z > x and z > y, but this does not answer whether z > x + y or z < x -y, does it?. In other words, treatments of A and B have effect of x, y. The null hypothesis is adding A + B has an effect of x + y, to examine this, I did some experiment, and I had a measurement of z, if z is not significant from x+y, then it would support the null hypothesis. I feel there is a subtle difference here compared to the test you have suggested, which is still very valuable, thank you.

Comment: @User2489612 Tukey's test compares the mean of every group with the mean of every other group (correctly for multiple comparisons) . I doubt it can do what you suggest: comparing A vs. the sum of A+B. It would be great if you could show us exactly what you mean.